# Showing a text after an itemize[<+->] with \pause creates double slide

Tags: beamer, overlays, pause

I've come across some strange interaction between overlay specification and `\pause`. Basically I have an itemize and after some text(or block). I want to step through the itemize and *after* that show the text/block.

I've tried to put a simple `\pause` between the `itemize` and the text, but in this way two slides are created, both with the full itemize and no text.

If I don't put the `\pause` the text is visible from the start(which I don't want).

I've already found a simple work-around: instead of using `itemize[<+->]` I can specify the slides on the items(e.g `item<1->, ...item<2->,... \pause`), but I don't like this solution for some reasons:

- I have to type more than before
- I have to hard-code the slide numbers
- This is solution is not robust. Modification on the item order, removal or addition of new items would break it.
- I think there has to be some better solution.

So, how should I do?

By the way, a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item A
        \item B
        \item C
    \end{itemize}

    \pause  % double pause here

    Some text.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is mainly to link this to a related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/682/86

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's a sync problem; if you add `\thebeamerpauses` in some places (to get the value of the `beamerpauses` counter), you can see what's going on:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item A\thebeamerpauses
\item B\thebeamerpauses
\item C\thebeamerpauses
\end{itemize}\thebeamerpauses
\pause
Some text.\thebeamerpauses 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

At the end of the `itemize` environment the counter has a value of four, and `\pause` steps it to 5, so the text will appear on the fifth slide.

To obtained the expected result you can use the optional argument of `\pause` and the value of the `beamerpauses`
 counter:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{itemize}
\pause[\thebeamerpauses]
Some text.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Another option is to use `\onslide<+->` instead of `\pause`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{itemize}
\onslide<+->{Some text.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've still got two questions: what If I have a `\begin{block} .. \end{block}` instead of the simple text?
Would you mind explaining a bit, if possible,  why a simple `\pause` wont give the desired output?

Comment: @Bakuriu same idea:    `\onslide<+->{\begin{block}{title}Some text.\end{block}}`. `\pause` can be used for basic overlay specifications; much finer control is obtained using `\only`, `\onslide`, `\uncover`.

Comment: @Bakuriu I updated my answer with another option.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But still I think that what I'm doing is not advanced. I wonder why something simple like this screws up `\pause`. I'd really like to understand why what I wrote does not work as intended.

Comment: @Bakuriu I just added an explanation of the unexpected result.

Comment: Perfect! I've still something I don't completely get about pauses count, but I think I'll eventually open a more specific question after reading again the beamer user guide.

Comment: I had the exactly the same question as the OP and your answer is perfect. Does that mean that `\onslide<+->` is always better? It seems to me so. I've found that `\onslide` doesn't require an argument. You can use it just like `\pause`.