# Beamer \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->} and \pause for texts below itemize environment

Tags: beamer, itemize, overlays, text, pause

Consider the following MWE in which I need to add some texts below itemize environment and I use \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}. When I add \pause above the texts, the result is that the slide with the two items is shown twice, which is undesirable. How can one show the slide only once?

```
    \documentclass{beamer} 
    \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
    \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{A MWE}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item 1
        \item item 2
    \end{itemize}
    \pause
    Some texts.
    \end{frame}     
    \end{document}
```

Comment: See also: [Showing a text after an itemize\[<+->\] with \pause creates double slide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71165/showing-a-text-after-an-itemize-with-pause-creates-double-slide). Using `\onslide<+->` instead of `\pause` should also work for your case. I have therefore voted to close your question as a duplicate to the previously mentioned one.

Comment: @Sebastiano The link answers my question. Thank you so much and please just close my question. Sorrry that I didn't find the link before. \pause[\thebeamerpauses] works like a charm.

Comment: @Glenn Why did you give me your "sorry"? :-) Don't worry, You will slowly learn how the site works. You think that I've been registered for 4 years and I don't know many options yet. My regards.

Comment: @@Sebastiano shake hands :-)