# Beamer pause after itemize

Tags: beamer, itemize, pause

If I pause after a list, I get an extra unnecessary slide. Consider the following code

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\pause
\[
  f(x) = x
\]
\end{frame}
```

If I compile this, I will get 4 slides. The first one shows item 1, the second one shows item 2, then the third slide shows the same as slide 2, then the equation appears on slide 4. Why does this happen? I know I could use `uncover` but I don't want to specify the slide number each time I do this.

Comment: This may help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71169/231952

Comment: As the link above suggests, `\pause` is really not meant to mix with more complex overlay constructs: it's very simple-minded

Comment: @Ivan That does it. Thanks for the help!