# How to show content only on the current slide in a Beamer specification?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Here is a beamer frame that shows "Item 1" in the first slide, "Item 1 Item 2" in the second and only "Item 1 Item 3" in the third. How can I get the same result without having to count the items for `\uncover<2>`?

I tried changing it to `\uncover<.>`, but then "Item 2" never appeared.

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \pause
        \uncover<2>{\item Item 2}
        \pause
        \item Item 3
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might use the `enumerate` environment that already has a counter `enumi` in it. You can combine that with the `\uncover` statement to create a new macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` syntax is out by one when not used with the default overlay specification in a list (see [How do I get the right number of pauses after a list in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/682/86) for where I encountered something a bit similar).

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \pause
        \uncover<.(1)>{\item Item 2}
        \pause
        \item Item 3
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-2> Item 1
        \item<2> Item 2
        \item<3> Item 3
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've clarified my question. I want the same behaviour as I'm getting, I just don't want to write the explicit `2`.