# Pause problem within `\item`

Tags: beamer, counters, pause

Look at this code:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1.
\item Item 2a.\pause Item 2b.
\item Item 3.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

I have `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}` activated.

What happens is not what I want. I want four slides such that in each slide a new item (or subitem) appears. What I get is four slides but only silde 1-2 and 4 like I want. Slide 3 looks like slide 2. So "Item 2b." is missing on slide 3.

How can this be solved?

Comment: This looks like a similar problem to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/682/86

Comment: If so, I've just posted the solution I ended up using which I think might answer your question.

Comment: In particular, replacing `\pause` with `\uncover<+->{...}` works like a charm.

Comment: Does the linked answer solve your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the right number of pauses after a list in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/682/how-do-i-get-the-right-number-of-pauses-after-a-list-in-beamer)